# Running MosaicToNewRaster tool fails. C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, error-000582

I am currently trying to run the MosaicToNewRaster tool via C#, on a set of TIFF files.  I am inputting all the required parameters but am still receiving:

> ERROR 000582:  error occurred during execution.

Which leads me to think one of my parameters are off.  Here is my code below:

```
Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
        try
        {
            int bands = 3;
            string imageryFolderPath = "Path\\ImageryFolder";
            string name = "texas2"

            ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.MosaicToNewRaster arcToolEngine = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.MosaicToNewRaster();
            string inputRasters = "";
            foreach (var pathToTiff in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imageryFolderPath))
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pathToTiff) == ".tif")
                {
                    inputRasters += Path.GetFileName(pathToTiff) + ";";
                }
            }
            arcToolEngine.input_rasters = inputRasters;
            arcToolEngine.number_of_bands = bands;
            arcToolEngine.output_location = imageryFolderPath;
            arcToolEngine.raster_dataset_name_with_extension = name + ".jpg";
            GP.Execute(arcToolEngine, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < GP.MessageCount; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GP.GetMessage(i));
                error += GP.GetMessage(i) + "\r\n";
            }                
        }
```

When the tool would fail, I would try running it again with bands = 1 and got the same error.  int bands, string imageryFolderPath, and string name, are all dummy variables in this example.  Are there any other parameters that I need to add to make this work?  Or is there a rule I am missing with my current parameters?

Comment: I would first verify that the issue is not with the input data by first running the tool with the same inputs/outputs in arcmap.

Comment: The MosaicToNewRaster in python takes a list (array) of strings but I do remember the semicolon separated list as input in earlier versions. There is very scant help for the geoprocessing tools in ArcObjects. Your inputRasters will have a trailing semicolon, that might be tripping the 582 *no real help on this error* message which equates to *I don't like one of your parameters but I'm not going to tell you why or even which one* try removing the last character from the string and if that doesn't work pass an array of strings and hope for the best, all else fails write a py script and shell it

Comment: @Hornbydd I ran the tool in arcmap on my input data and successfully received an output.

Comment: That's been a worth while check, ensuring your data does actually process. I would explore what @MichaelStimson is suggesting.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have gotten it to work with a single Tiff file now, it turns input_rasters need to have the entire path to the Tiff files.  But as of now, I cannot get it to work with 2 or more Tiff files in the same directory.  

input_raster = "path\\myImageFolder\\img1.tiff;" Will work
input_raster = "path\\myImageFolder\\img1.tiff;path\\myImageFolder\\img2.tiff;" Does NOT work.  

I think the issue is obviously how I am concatenating 2 or more Tiff files together for Input_path.  I have tested running 2 or more Tiff files in ArcMap as well, and they outputted as expected.

Comment: Another clue that could potentially help.  I was successfully able to run the tool using a tiff file as the output as well.  Unfortunately this will not suffice as we want a jpg file since it is a smaller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by running MosaicToNewRaster in Python.  I inputted the exact same parameters and no errors were thrown.